# Madvertise Callback Listener

Tags: android, eclipse, admob

I want to switch ne advertise depending on which is available. So I got this code:

```
public class ActivityMain extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
     private MadvertiseView mMadView;
     private AdView mAdmView;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    
    mAdmView = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.admad);
    mMadView = (MadvertiseView)findViewById(R.id.madad);
    
    mMadView.setMadvertiseViewCallbackListener(new MadvertiseViewCallbackListener() {
        @Override public void onLoaded(boolean success, MadvertiseView arg1) {
             if (success) {
                  if (mAdmView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                       mAdmView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                  }
                  mMadView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
             } else {
                  mMadView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
             }
        }
    });
}`
```

Now Im getting 2 errors and downt know how to fix it....
This is the first:
The type new MadvertiseView.MadvertiseViewCallbackListener(){} must implement the inherited abstract method MadvertiseView.MadvertiseViewCallbackListener.onError(Exception)

And this is the Second:
The type new MadvertiseView.MadvertiseViewCallbackListener(){} must implement the inherited abstract method MadvertiseView.MadvertiseViewCallbackListener.onIllegalHttpStatusCode(int, String)

I Hope anyone can help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are implementing an interface which has the three methods `onLoaded`, `onIllegalHttpStatusCode` and `onError`, so just add this below your `onLoaded` method:

```
@Override
public void onIllegalHttpStatusCode(int statusCode, String message) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void onError(Exception exception) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
}
```